# Set highest Role of User or highest Role in Server

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to set the highest role of a user? I want to silentban someone, so I create a silent role, but the role is at the lowest position. I want to set this to the highest role of a user that the permissions of the silent role are used

Sry for bad english I hope you understand this

Comment: I think you want to say that you want to make `silent` role higher than others. You can use `setPosition` for this

Comment: ok and how do I set the position to the highest possible position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the role to the highest possible position on the guild you can do:

```js
// guild = <Guild>
// role = <Role>
const highest = guild.me.roles.highest.position;
role.setPosition(highest-1);
```

You cannot set the position individually for each user if that's what you wanted